# Postgresql: find closest matching pairs in two arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops, sorting, find

I have two tables in Postgresql:

Table `a`:

```
name | power
:--- | :----
a1   | 12   
a2   | 6    
a3   | 3    
a4   | 1
```

Table `b`:

```
name | power
:--- | :----
b1   | 11   
b2   | 4
```

I would like to efficiently (I need to perform this query with 10Hz) find the closest matching powers, i.e. the result should be

```
name | power | name | power
:--- | :---- | :--- | :----
a1   | 12    | b1   | 11   
a3   | 3     | b2   | 4
```

I've implemented it using a loop, however, if there is a more efficient way to find the solution, I would be glad.

Many thanks

Comment: Please describe your "arrays". Are these arrays of tuples? Two-dimensional arrays? A column with multiple two-element arrays? Table structure would help.

Comment: Both tables are very simple (b has the same structure as a): 
`CREATE TABLE a
(
  name text, 
  power real 
 );`

Comment: Can one b value match two a values (e.g. if there were a pair (a5, 10), the pair (b1, 11) would match both)

Comment: Yes, this can be the case. Then, one of the following solutions would be ok: only map one, or map both.

Answer (score 2):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dcc7b212c35295038bc4e15556493fe9)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.name)
    a.*,
    b.*
FROM a CROSS JOIN b
ORDER BY b.name, abs(a.power - b.power)
```

1. `CROSS JOIN` all records to be able to compare all `a` values with all `b` values
2. Calculate the absolute difference between these pairs to find the minimum
3. `DISTINCT ON (b.name)` gives out the first records that includes a certain `b.name` value (because it is ordered by the difference, it takes the record which has the smallest diff to an `a` value)

Comment: @Jens If one answer solves your question, please do not forget to accept (for closing the question) (click the check mark at the top left corner of the relevant answer)

Answer (score 2):

@S-Man's solution is likely the best solution, but in some cases it may be faster to use a lateral join:

```
SELECT sub.*, b.*
FROM b
JOIN LATERAL 
  (select a.* FROM a ORDER BY abs(a.power-b.power) LIMIT 1) sub 
ON TRUE;
```

If you want all the a's returned, with b appearing multiple times, just flip this around:

```
SELECT a.*, sub.*
FROM a
JOIN LATERAL 
  (select b.* FROM b ORDER BY abs(a.power-b.power) LIMIT 1) sub 
ON TRUE;
```

Comment: Upvote for the idea! :) You could change the `JOIN LATERAL ... ON TRUE` into `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`